# Windows Media Player 11 doesn't download codecs for avi files

Tags: windows-xp, video, windows-media-player, codec

I've got some avi files that WMP will play the audio for but not the video. Why doesn't WMP download the codecs it needs? Or is the solution to download a codec pack and install that manually?

In "Options > Player" the "Download codecs automatically" option is checked.

I've installed VLC so I can watch them, which I'm quite happy about so I don't need a recommendation for a new player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avi is not a codec or file format. It's a container format... It means that inside an avi-file, about any codec can be used. Some codecs are just not integrated in WMP and Microsoft will or can not integrate those. (Usually for legal reasons)

Installing codec packs would do, I've always used the codec packs from http://www.free-codecs.com/ (The [K-Lite](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/K_Lite_Codec_Pack.htm) Codec pack should provide in all your needs) and it worked for me. Of course, VLC would do too! ;)

Comment: I know that avi is just the container. I was wondering why WMP didn't go off and download the codecs it needs.

Comment: The reason fot that is also mentioned in my answer.